# How to call a custom attribute in homepage.phtml in Magento 2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2

I have created Products attribute name as Electronics, I want to call that attribute in my HomePage which is homepage.phtml I don't know how to do that, please help me.
Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

object method

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
echo $product->getElectronics();
```

Factory Method

```
<?php
namespace Meetanshi\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

phtml file code

```
$product=$this->getLoadProduct(20);
echo $product->getElectronics();
```

In Magento 2.1

```
      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
      ) {
          parent::__construct($context);

          $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
      }
      public function getProduct($productId)
      {
         return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
      }
  }
```

In phtml file

```
$data=$block->getProduct(Product_id);
echo $data->getElectronics();
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me where to keep object method,factory method and all?

Comment: These three are the different methods.
You can use first one object method and use it in homepage.phtml file.

Comment: The code which you have given me above is for Magento1.x or Magento2.x?
I've tried it for magento 2.x but it is not working.
Getting error as : We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Comment: can you please share homepage.phtml file? Its for Magento 2

Comment: <div class="main_bottom_right">
   <div class="right_cont">
      <h3 class="right_title_gift"><span><span>Electronics</span></span></h3>
      <!-- Beth h3 -->
      <div class="best_week">
         <ul class="products-grid">

here I want to call the attribute

         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: <?php
$product_id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);?>
<div class="main_bottom_right"> <div class="right_cont"> <h3 class="right_title_gift"><span><span>Electronics</span></spa‌​n></h3> <!-- Beth h3 --> <div class="best_week"> <ul class="products-grid"><?php echo $product->getElectronics();?></ul> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: How I get the product id?
I should be dynamic.

Comment: Hi, How many products do you want to show on home page?

Comment: 6 products at a time.

Comment: Random or from any specific category?

Comment: Not from category, from a specific attribute.
Suppose I have created a attribute name as GiftIdeas, the products that are selected for Giftideas must display on the index page.
Please help me.

Comment: I am getting this error while using th above code: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.